# When clicking a button, or resize window, the layout moves, "jumps".

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

This question is similar to [FXML - Text Field Moves To The Right Upon Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613679/fxml-text-field-moves-to-the-right-upon-button-click) but it doesn´t help my case.

I have a BorderPane, with a logo/text in the top, and the main contents in center.

```
<BorderPane id="mainpane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1200.0" stylesheets="@/css/biomat.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <HBox id="maintop" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
         <children>
            <Label text="Header">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Verdana" size="48.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
   <center>
      <VBox id="maincenter" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ProgressIndicator prefHeight="97.0" prefWidth="800.0" />
            <Label text="Loading...">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

The main contents is a couple of buttons which are displayed after some loading is done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<VBox fx:id="mainmenupane" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="0" prefWidth="0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.MainMenuController">
   <children>
      <GridPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button id="button1" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="100.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button 1" GridPane.columnIndex="0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="50.0" right="50.0" top="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button id="button2" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="100.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button 2" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="50.0" right="50.0" top="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <GridPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" valignment="CENTER" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="button3" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="100.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button 3" GridPane.columnIndex="0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="50.0" right="50.0" top="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <GridPane alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" valignment="CENTER" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="button4" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button 4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Now the interesting part that I don´t understand. Click all but the first (#button1) button and the whole layout moves upward a couple of pixels, it happens once, then the layout has "settled".

A workaround I found, is to force a layout pass after I have added the contents with the buttons.

```
borderPane.setCenter(node);
borderPane.layout();
```

Obviously I don´t like the above solution, instead I want to understand why the layout has not settled correctly in the first place.

Comment: Do you have any effects (like drop shadow) in place?

Comment: Yes, the buttons have a drop shadow. But I actually tried disable that, but it didn´t fix the problem. The " layout jump" happens anyway.

Comment: Does [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2577503) help?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried adding some padding around the VBox but the layout moves upward anyway. All is fine when I click #button1. The movement only happens when clicking #button2, #button3 or #button4.

Comment: Did you check out what happens in your application with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)? Once you have figured out which value changes, then you can add a listener on it to find the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on ScenicView. I hadn´t used it before. Anyway, what I found was that this maybe can be an OS X issue. I noticed that the movement of the buttons also occurs when I long-click on the task bar on OS X. Its all very strange. I will try running the app on Windows 7.

Comment: Just tested on Windows 7. Same issue there.

Comment: Ok, I found what is causing this. For this particular view I am using a programmatic binding:
`public void initialize() {`
    `button4.prefWidthProperty().bind(button1.widthProperty());`
    `button4.prefHeightProperty().bind(button1.heightProperty());`
    `}`

That is whats causing the layout to jump once. Now I am going to figure out why it happens!